# Helper method to construct icon link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome, view-helpers

I have this line in my helper method

```
links << {:link => link_to('Overview', overview_index_path, :class => "bold"),
              :active => (params[:controller] == "Overview")}
```

I want to link to a font-awesone icon instead of the text "Overview"

```
<i class="icon-bar-chart"></i>
```

I know this is something easy, but i can't remember it right now. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: TRy links << {:link => link_to('<i class="icon-bar-chart"></i>', overview_index_path, :class => "bold"),
              :active => (params[:controller] == "Overview")}

Comment: i tried that, it links to the text "<i class="icon-bar-chart"></i>"

Comment: you have to use html_safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
links << {:link => link_to('<i class="icon-bar-chart"></i>'.html_safe, overview_index_path, :class => "bold"),
              :active => (params[:controller] == "Overview")}
```